# Error en evento con JFrame java

Tags: java, botón, jframe

mi problema es en java con los jframe que, al momento de dar al boton limpiar se limpia la entrada y salida, pero cuando vuelvo a introducir la entrada, me marca error al dar el botton de mostrar, que lo que haría seria ejecutar los if para arrojar el resultado pero no me arroja de nuevo la salida, sin embargo si puedo volver a escribir la entrada.

Aquí estan los códigos que tiene cada boton.

```js
                                     
    private void btnMostrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        if("".equals(txtEdad.getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Deberias introducir datos");
        }
        else{
            pnlSalida.setVisible(true);
            int Edad=Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText());
             if(Edad>=0 && Edad<=6)
    
     lblSalida.setText("La etapa de la vida es la INFANCIA");
 
 if(Edad>6 && Edad<=12)
    
     lblSalida.setText("La etapa de la vida es la NINIEZ");
 
 if(Edad>12 && Edad<=18)
    
     lblSalida.setText("La etapa de la vida es la ADOLESCENCIA");
 
 if(Edad>18 && Edad<=25)
    
     lblSalida.setText("La etapa de la vida es la JUVENTUD");
 
 if(Edad>25 && Edad<=60)
    
     lblSalida.setText("La etapa de la vida es la ADULTEZ");
 
 if(Edad>61)
    
     lblSalida.setText("La etapa de la vida es la VEJEZ");
 
            
            btnMostrar.setEnabled(false);
            txtEdad.setEnabled(false);
            lblSalida.setEnabled(false);
       
        }// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void btnLimpiarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
       
              
        txtEdad.setText(" ");
        lblSalida.setText(" ");
        pnlSalida.setVisible(false);
        txtEdad.setEnabled(true);
        btnMostrar.setEnabled(true);
        lblSalida.setEnabled(true);
        
        
// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void btnSalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        System.exit(0);        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
```

Comment: Hola! Cuál es el error? Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento del sitio y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

En el evento de **limpiar** estas ingresando el caracter de espacio al hacer `txtEdad.setText(" ")`, y ahí está el problema por que después en el evento **mostrar** lo **parseas** a int con `int Edad=Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText())`, pero `txtEdad` ahora tiene un  espacio `" "` cuando el método `Integer.parseInt` espera solo caracteres numéricos. Es una **excepción unchecked**, o sea son las que el compilador no te obliga a capturar o controlar, por ende se producen en tiempo de ejecución. El nombre de la excepción es `NumberFormatException`. Para solucionarlo usa `txtEdad.setText("")` (comillas solas) o `txtEdad.setText(null)`. Y ya que estás podrías controlar la excepción con un bloque `try catch` para cuando el usuario te ingresa un caracter **no numérico**, y así el error no se produce, solo se detiene el programa en ese punto y muestra un mensaje con información de la excepción más el mensaje que quieras agregarle. Asi:

```
try {

    // Instruccion que puede causar una excepción
    int Edad=Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText());

} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

    // Instruccion/es cuando se produce una excepción
    txtEdad.setText(null);//limpiamos el campo de texto
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"debe ingresar solo valores numéricos");//mostramos mensaje
}
```